# How to improve my question “How can warm steel and wood merge together?”?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Could someone please explain to me why my question [How can warm steel and wood merge together?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/164328/123136) was downvoted, and what I should correct for the next time?

Comment: There's a steep learning curve to using Stack Exchange sites, as so many things are fundamentally different from how they are on other sites.
To make it worse, each individual SE site has its own, sometimes difficult to understand, rules for what is considered "on-topic". Don't worry about anonymous and unexplained down-votes. You'll get used to them. I get them all the time (and my overall SE reputation is nearly 40,000). Remember that in terms of reputation points it takes 5 down-votes to cancel a single up-vote. Some of the most interesting posts receive large numbers of both up and down. T

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At face value a [downvote](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) implies a person did not find the post useful. Voting is anonymous and I cannot confirm the reasons, but in the case of your post I could hazard a guess as to why it was downvoted: (1) the connection with chemistry is flimsy (imo it is sufficiently related to chemistry but it might equally well have been posted on some other site, say physics SE); (2) insufficient detail on the  technique involved. Although perhaps explained in the youtube video,  please do not rely on external sources that might later disappear to support a post, rather incorporate all relevant information; (3) [perhaps there is information on the site that would answer your question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), had you bothered to look. Repetition is somewhat frowned upon at the site.

New arrivals at the site are often surprised and probably discouraged when they receive downvotes.  Editing a post if sometimes enough to assuage critics. If you are here thinking you might have additional questions do not feel too discouraged to try again, but you may find a more receptive audience if you pay attention to these comments.